# MYSQL Counting the number of records that are associated

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Suppose I have a cat table and a catherder table with a one catherder to many cats relationship. How would I write a query that along with typical attributes like color of hat, height, etc, I could have a count of how many cats each herder has where each cat herder is one record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT catherder.*, count(cat.id) AS cats_count
FROM catherder join cat
     on catherder.id = cat.catherder_id
```

Comment: I think you may have forgot the AS keyword m8!

Comment: I don't have a join table because it's a one to many. Each cat has a catherder id.

Comment: It is in my answer, "...with a one catherder to many cats relationship." Thanks though, your answer will be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (not tested)

```
SELECT color,height,COUNT(cat.id) AS cats FROM 
cats RIGHT JOIN catherder ON cats.id = catherder.id GROUP BY catherder.id;
```

Comment: cats.catherder_id = catherder.id is perhaps what you meant?